# Iterate over combinations of elements of a vector and manipulate elements

Tags: rust

I'd like to get all combinations of the elements of a vector. I'm using itertools' combinations() function. That's fine, but now I want to manipulate elements of the vector. Therefore I need an iterator that yields mutable references of the elements of the vector...

My code basically looks like follows:

```
let mut v: Vec<MyType> = vec![];
for vpair in v.iter_mut().combinations(2) {
     vpair.first().unwrap().do_something(vpair.last().unwrap());
}
```

By calling `do_something()` I want to manipulate `vpair.first().unwrap()` and `vpair.last().unwrap()` on each iteration.

The error I receive is:

`the trait std::clone::Clone is not implemented for &mut MyType`

Can I somehow manage this issue or am I completely on the wrong track?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do this. The [`itertools::Itertools::combinations`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.2/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.combinations) is defined as

```rust
fn combinations(self, k: usize) -> Combinations<Self>
where
    Self: Sized,
    Self::Item: Clone,
```

It says the items of underlying iterator need to be `Clone`. After all, all combinations contain every item more than once by definition. But [mutable reference never implements `Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#additional-implementors) since it is exclusive in Rust.

OTOH, if your `MyType` is itself `Clone`, you can try:

```rust
let mut v: Vec<MyType> = vec![];
for vpair in v.into_iter().combinations(2) {
     vpair.first().unwrap().do_something(vpair.last().unwrap());
}
```

Since you own items returned from `into_iter`, you can do whatever you want with them. But every round of the loop manipulates independent clones of them, that may or may not be what you intend to do.

Comment: I am new to rust so might be wrong, but couldn't you use your second example with indexes, and get the mutable reference directly from the original vector.